# Slider not working on safari

Tags: ios, css, safari, slider

I have an odd problem where I have built a basic slider but instead of the text sliding in on IOS it just appears.  I thought it was the transform: translateX css statement but I've put in all the options and I still have the problem.  Any ideas?

If you go to http://www.ospreyactionsports.co.uk/ and set the viewport to below 767 you'll see the confidence banners slider.  Below is the css for the slider for reference:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .banners {
    height: 37px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .banners .banner {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
    -o-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  .banners .displayed {
    display: block;
    margin-left: calc(25%);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transition: .3s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    width: 310px;
  }
}
```